# is it possible to assign a prototype on an existing object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

if i have:

```
function Base (){
    this.sayHi = function(){
        alert('hi');
    }
}

function Thing (val){
    this.value = val;
}

var bob = new Thing("bob");
```

Is there some way I can now say that bob inherits from Base so that I could call:

```
bob.sayHi();
```

Basically have all the methods and properties of the Base class available on that instance?

**A more relevant example with solution based on CMS's post:**

Here Items could represent data returned by the server..

```
var Items = [
    { sku: 123, type:'buggy', title:'This is a title', description: 'this is a description' },
    { sku: 234, type: 'baby-monitor', title: 'This is a title 2', description: 'this is a description 2' }
]

function ItemMethods() {
    this.BannerHTML = function () {
        return '<div class="banner _item_' + this.type + '_' + this.sku + '"><h2>' +
            this.title + '</h2><p>' +
            this.description + '</p></div>';
    };
}

Items.GetBySKU = function (code) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
        if (Items[i].sku == code) {
            return Items[i];
        }
    }
};

$.each(Items, function (i, item) {
    ItemMethods.apply(item);
});

alert(Items.GetBySKU(234).BannerHTML());
```

Any further comments or solutions gladly accepted.. always interested in potential solutions to a problem ;-)

Comment: you might appreciate this article I ran into the other day, http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

Comment: You might want to consider changing the title of this since it turns out to not be about changing existing portotypes but shows up in google results for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the properties that you create within the constructor, have nothing to do with the constructor's `prototype`, they are *own properties* of the object you create using `new Base();`, they are not inherited. However, I think what you want to do it to  *apply* the `Base` constructor function on the newly created object of `Thing`:

```
function Base (){
    this.sayHi = function(){
        alert('hi');
    }
}

function Thing (val){
    Base.apply(this, arguments);
    this.value = val;
}

var bob = new Thing("bob");
bob.sayHi();
```

Note that `bob` will not inherit from `Base` (it won't have access to properties added to `Base.prototype`)

```
bob instanceof Base;  // false
bob instanceof Thing; // true
```

Comment: what about for an instance.. can i do "Base.apply(bob,arguments);" somewhere after creating bob?

Comment: @gordatron, yes, that's absolutely possible, you can re-use functions at any time... Check this article: [A fresh look at JavaScript Mixins](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/)

Answer (score 7):

**No.** There is no way to assign a different *[[prototype]]* of an *existing object*, at least according the the specification. The *[[prototype]]* is the object resulting from the evaluation (aka "contained in") of the constructors `prototype` property *at time of new object creation* and cannot be reassigned later. (I wish it could be officially changed, but alas it is an unsupported operation and can *generally* be emulated via different methods.)

Some browsers/environments may choose to expose post-creation *[[prototype]]* assignment with non-standard approaches. The *[[prototype]] object(s)* can be modified (e.g. adding to String.prototype), or singleton functions can be added to the target object (see CMS's answer), or existing objects can be wrapped (essentially a dynamic "subclass") -- depending upon requirements and restrictions.

Also, there are no "classes" in Javascript: while "classical single-inheritance objected oriented classes" can be implemented in Javascript, I find it limiting to restrict oneself to the model or use such terminology in general. A language wants to be what it is.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much! Lots of very useful info and pointers.. I kind of structured my questions in the most expressive way I could without 300  characters ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can create a subclass of an other by setting the subclass' prototype to an instance of the base class:

```
function BaseClass() {
    this.baseFunction = function() {
    };
};

function SubClass() {
};
SubClass.prototype = new BaseClass;
SubClass.prototype.someFunction = function() {
};

// create an instance of SubClass
var obj = new SubClass;

// SubClass truly extends BaseClass
obj instanceof BaseClass // true
obj instanceof SubClass // true

// the instance has both methods of BaseClass and SubClass
typeof obj.someFunction // Function
typeof obj.baseFunction // Function
```

This is the equivalent of `class SubClass extends BaseClass` in java.

---

If you also modify the prototypes after that.

If you add functions and properties to the prototype of the object's constructor, the functions and properties will be available on all the instances.

Here is an example:

```
function Thing (val){
    this.value = val;
}

var bob = new Thing("bob");

console.log(bob.foo); // undefined

Thing.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo!');
};

console.log(bob.foo); // function()
bob.foo(); // foo!
```

Now if you want to extend all Thing instances with Base, you can do it like this:

```
var base = new Base;
for (var k in base) {
    Thing.prototype[k] = base[k];
}
```

Or if you want to make Thing instances extend Base: (i.e. don't override methods that are already in Thing)

```
var base = new Base;
for (var k in base) {
    if (Thing.prototype[k]) continue;
    Thing.prototype[k] = base[k];
}
```

---

If you only want to extend a unique object instance, just assign to it:

```
var bob = new Thing("bob");
var base = new Base();

bob.sayHi = base.sayHi;

bob.sayHi();
```

You can also call a function in the context of an object, without even assign the function to the object:

```
var base = new Base();
base.sayHi.call(bob);
```

Comment: but nothing like bob.prototype = Base? just for that instance?

Comment: If you want to add a function to only that instance, just assign the function to the instance: `bob.sayHi = theFunction;` (or `var base = new Base; bob.sayHi = base.sayHi;`)

Comment: You can also call sayHi in the context of `bob`: `var base = new Base; base.sayHi.call(bob);`

Comment: all very handy thanks! I am going to use the Base.apply(bob) method proposed by CMS.

Comment: what you actually wanted is just to extend Base with Thing ?

Comment: I've added the correct equivalent of `class SubClass extends BaseClass`.

Comment: I am looking to apply the methods and properties of a class to an instance (of anything). i will update the question with a more realistic example for what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1) You can add Base's constructor definition directly to the bob instance

```
Base.call(bob);
bob.sayHi(); //hi
```

2) Or you can augment Thing.prototype with Base's constructor definition. The bob instance can access its prototype's new properties even if it was created before they were added

```
var bob = new Thing("bob");
Base.call(Thing.prototype);
bob.sayHi(); //hi
```