# Is there a way to change the prototype of an object in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype

In IE you can't use `obj.__proto__ = some_proto`, but you can go around this deficit by using inheritance through function, e.g.:

```
func = function(){}
func.prototype = proto
obj = new func
```

The problem with this roundabout is that old references to `obj` are lost and won't point to the new `obj` with `proto` as prototype. Is there anyway to change the prototype of existing objects in IE?

Comment: No. `__proto__` is just a hack (it's non-standard) and you should never use it anyway. It is currently not possible in JS to change the prototype of an existing object. *related*: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13235313/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7223353/218196

Comment: @FelixKling: Make it an answer

Comment: Yea, i was guessing it probably isn't, but just wanted to be sure. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

`__proto__` is just a hack and you should never use it anyway (it's not a standard feature). It is currently not possible in JS to change the prototype of an existing object.

Related questions/answers: [Changing prototype of an object which was created with literal initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13235313/218196), https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223353/218196

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, IE 11 supports the new Object.setPrototypeOf method. To be use with caution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf